# Knockout/Typescript ko.observables with objects

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, knockout.js

Im doing the Introduction tutorial for Knockout, the second part of the tutorial is about observables, I have the following code on my .ts (later .js):

```
/// <reference path="../typings/index.d.ts" />

$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
});

class Person {

    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;

    constructor(firstName: string, lastName: string) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName
    }
}

var ViewModel = function () {

    var person = new Person('MyName', 'MyLastName');
    this.person = person;

    this.person = ko.observable(person.firstName);
    this.person = ko.observable(person.lastName);
};
```

and I have the following in my cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    <script src="~/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/bower_components/knockout/dist/knockout.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/greeter.js"></script>

    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        <p>FirstName: </p> <p data-bind="text: person.firstName"></p>
        <p>LastName: </p> <p data-bind="text: person.lastName"></p>

        <p>First name: <input data-bind="value: person.firstName" /></p>
        <p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: person.lastName" /></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the web app, instead of showing "MyName" and "MyLastName" on my `<p>` tags it shows nothing and when I write in my `<input>` it does not show anything in my `<p>` tags.

So the question is, it is possible to change attributes of a class or I need it change only variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution is to change the `Person` class to create observables in the constructor:

```
class Person {
    firstName: KnockoutObservable<string>;
    lastName: KnockoutObservable<string>;

    constructor(firstName: string, lastName: string) {
        this.firstName = ko.observable(firstName);
        this.lastName = ko.observable(lastName);
    }
}

var ViewModel = function () {
    this.person = new Person('MyName', 'MyLastName');
};
```

It would also be better to create a class for the ViewModel.

Comment: I Agree with your answer, I saw it in the same tutorial and makes sense, less writing.

Comment: Im having a problem, the values are not being binded to my p tags

Comment: Are you using the `text` binding? Also check the developer tools console to see if there are any errors. Also have you installed the knockout types for typescript?

Comment: I found an answer, I made a different question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43453285/typescript-and-knockout-js

It was about binding to the incorrect property of an html tag. In this new scenario it was a combobox (select) so the correct property to bind was value and not text. Thanks to your answer for this question tho, at the moment I wrote the above comment I did not realize I was binding to the incorrect property because I did not know,

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found the problem, it was on my typescript, instead of:

```
var ViewModel = function () {

    var person = new Person('MyName', 'MyLastName');
    this.person = person;

    this.person = ko.observable(person.firstName);
    this.person = ko.observable(person.lastName);
};
```

It should be:

```
var ViewModel = function () {

    var person = new Person('MyName', 'MyLastName');
    this.person = person;

    this.person.firstName = ko.observable(person.firstName);
    this.person.lastName = ko.observable(person.lastName); 
};
```

I did not tell the function that should change the person attributes.