# Typescript and Knockout.js

Tags: html, typescript, mvvm, knockout.js

Im trying to get this code working, Im new to typescript and knockout.js I have been doing this piece of code in another way but someone told me this could be a better way to improve the existing code, the problem is, is not working, maybe is a typo but Im not finding it.

This is my Typescript:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/index.d.ts" />

$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new ABMAlumnosModel());
});

class Alumno {
    Legajo: KnockoutObservable<string>;
    Nombre: KnockoutObservable<string>;
    Apellido: KnockoutObservable<string>;
    Dni: KnockoutObservable<number>;
    Carrera: KnockoutObservable<string>;
    Turno: KnockoutObservable<string>;

    constructor(Legajo: string, Nombre: string, Apellido: string, Dni: number, Carrera: string, Turno: string) {
        this.Nombre = ko.observable(Nombre);
        this.Apellido = ko.observable(Apellido);
        this.Legajo = ko.observable(Legajo);
        this.Carrera = ko.observable(Carrera);
        this.Turno = ko.observable(Turno);
        this.Dni = ko.observable(Dni);
    }
}


var ABMAlumnosModel = function () {
    this.alumno = new Alumno('sdsdf', 'dsfdsf', 'sdfsdf', 0, 'dsfdsf', 'sdfsdfsd');
}
```

And this is my cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>ABM_Alumnos</title>
    <script src="~/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/bower_components/knockout/dist/knockout.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/ABM_Alumnos.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Style/ABM_Alumnos.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="titulo">
        <bold><p>ABM Alumnos del Instituo ESBA</p></bold>
    </div>

    <div>
        <form>

            <div class="float-left c-input-wrapper">
                <p>Nombre: </p><input type="text" data-bind="text: alumno.Nombre"/>   
                <p>Legajo: </p><input type="text" data-bind="text: alumno.Legajo"/>
                <p>Carrera: </p> <select id="alumno.Carreras"></select>
            </div>

            <div class="float-left t-input-wrapper">
                <p>Apellido: </p><input type="text" data-bind="text: alumno.Apellido"/>
                <p>Dni: </p><input type="text" data-bind="text: alumno.Dni" />
                <p>Turno: </p> <select id="alumno.Turnos"></select>
            </div>

            <div class="clear"></div>

            @*<div id="Agregar">
                <button data-bind="click: GetTurnos">Agregar</button>
            </div>*@



        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I remember doing the observables inside model instead of calling a constructor, but I feel is the same. The thing is, the input texts are not being filled with the data I put when I instance an object `Alumno`.

I tried to find some info into the knockout tutorial and different typescript pages. Maybe im binding the data incorrectly.

Comment: For the person who downvoted, please give a reason so I can Improve the question, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found the problem, it was pretty simple, but honestly passed under my radar. The problem was in my html, the correct property to write on this input was `value` and not `text`, I was doing another tutorial where I had to bind data on a `<p>` tag, and that is `text`.